# the executed section

Tags: exe, portable-executable, coff

How can I retrieve in exe file point where IP is pointing to on the beginning ??
Is it pointing always on the start of .text segment ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at `AddressOfEntryPoint` member of the `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680339.aspx) or start `dumpbin.exe My.exe /headers` and look at "entry point" in the "OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES" part of the output (6-th line from the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, IP points to the .text section. But this is not a requirement of the PE Specification. When a PE Section has been encrypted or compressed (like using UPX), IP is redirected to a proxy. By the way, the PE specification also gives a hint about the fact that the name of the Sections are not standardized. Some programs have 'unusual' sections names (e.g. Exeinfo PE).